# JSON stringify json object typescript / angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, stringify

Hey I'm trying do stringify a JSON object or rather what i believe is a JSON object. Below is my current code:

```
const user: any = {
      Username: username,
      Password: password
};

console.log('Data: ' + JSON.stringify(user));
```

The console only prints out:

```
Data: {}
```

How can i modify my "JSON object" so it doesn't return empty?

Comment: Your object is incorrect, there are no values, something like this will work `const user: any = {username:'John', password: '123'};`

Comment: Sorry username and password are variables passed down, but come to think of it they might not be initialized.... Stupid :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get an empty object if both the username and password variables are undefined.  Angular won't create any keys that have undefined values.

The object the way you have it (without quotes) is referencing JavaScript variables and they may not contain actual values and not variable references:

```
{
  Username: usernameVariable,
  Password: passwordVariable
}
```

If you haven't defined those variables yet then they will have a value of "undefined".

However, if you have quotes around the values then they will be actual values in the JSON object:

```
{
  Username: "usernameValue",
  Password: "passwordValue"
}
```

Comment: Undefined values?! You men like creating a model for the object?!  I can achieve the desired result if i do `JSON.stringify({Usename:username, Password})` why?! But i need it as a variable later.

Comment: At the moment you array translate to `CONST user` array of type `any ` that hold `Username` variable of type `username` of `null` and a `Password` variable of type `password` with value of `null`. So you need to either put `'` or `"` around the values to tell it they are values not types.

Comment: It's not Angular that isn't creating the keys with undefined values.  That happens in the `JSON.stringify` function, which isn't part of Angular.  JS will happily create such an object just fine.  See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for more info.

Comment: Partially right, I discovered that the variables I was referencing never got initialized. But thanks both of you for the tip on Angular and undefined values.

Answer (score -2):

I think that this would work...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var user = {
    Username: username, 
    Password: password
    };

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(user);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myJSON;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is assuming you have username and password coming in.

Comment: Aaaaaand I just saw this had the angular tag... I'm an idiot

Comment: That aside, this is still a bad answer.  It has no explanation and doesn't actually fix anything.